# Failed to get remote view controller with error: Error: domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain, code=0

Tags: swift, sfsafariviewcontroller, ios10.3, xcode8

[image]Failed to get remote view controller with error: Error: domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain, code=0

I am using the Facebook to login/ Google to login etc.

While trying to open Safari it always showing white screen after a while.

Thanks

Comment: can you show your appDelegate

Comment: I have added have look @DarkInnocence

Comment: Simply restarting my phone helped solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

try with this statement:-

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
    }
```